# Add event handler for touch event on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, addeventlistener

I'm modifying some code and trying to make the `button` elements listen to a mobile touch.  Here's the code:

```
  // Create training buttons and info texts    
  for(let i=0;i<NUM_CLASSES; i++){
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.style.marginBottom = '10px';

  // Create training button
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerText = "Train "+i;
  div.appendChild(button);

  // Listen for mouse events when clicking the button
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', () => this.training = i);
  button.addEventListener('mouseup', () => this.training = -1);
```

I've tried to add the following code to handle mobile events, but this did not work:

```
  button.addEventListener('touchstart', () => this.training = i);
  button.addEventListener('touchend', () => this.training = -1);
```

I've also tried to simulate mouse presses with touches but this approach does not work.  I'm also open to jQuery solutions and breaking the original functionality to make mobile work.

The original code is here:
https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachable-machine-boilerplate/blob/master/main.js.

Comment: You are trying to use arrow functions with an event handler, and trying to use `this` inside it.  `this` is not bound with an arrow function.  Change it to a normal function to use `this` or pass in the event to the handler and use `e.target` .  Or is that intentional?

Comment: The original arrow functions worked for mouse event handling.  I don't know enough about javascript to say if the original people who coded this intended it this way, but the way that I interpreted it was that the function variable `this.training` would be updated to either the button number (there are 3, labeled from 0 to 2) or `-1` if no button is being pressed.